# What is the correct variable type for a single value in raster calculator, modelbuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

The equation includes several raster and several single values, and I want to do it in raster calculator, modelbuilder for the purpose of multiple calculations. In raster part, it is ok to select raster band, but how about the single values? I have selected any value under the function of create variable, but it does not work.

The expression is Cos("%Solar Zenith Angle%") * Cos("%Slope%") + Sin("%Solar Zenith Angle%") * Sin("%Slope%") * Cos("%Solar Azimuth Angle%" - "%Aspect%")

P.S. Slope and aspect are both raster, and Solar Zenith Angle and Solar Azimuth Angle are only single values.

It works, when I use raster calculator directly, so I think the problem probably comes from the variable type.

Any hint?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your expression with us?

Comment: When you create the variables, you select "a single value" and "Raster Layer"?

Comment: @Barbarossa I selected "raster band" and "any value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your variable inside of float() i.e. float(%Variable%).  This will be necessary for data types Double or Any Value.

```
float(%Any Value%) or float(%Double%)
```

You can also create a variable of type Long, if a decimal place is not necessary.

```
%Long%
```