# Unable to Use Defined Variable for Raster Calculation in Python

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, error-000732

I am trying to open a text file that contains one line, which is a number. I am then trying to define this as a variable to use in my raster calculation/map algebra. I am currently running on Windows 7.

**Command Prompt Error**

`RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset slope1 does not exist or is not supported`

**input2 File**

`-.0000462`

**Script Example**

`slope1 = open('C:\Users\Apples\Documents\ArcGIS\Blueberry_Cobbler\input2', 'r').read()`

`outraster = ((slope1 * Power(inraster ,3)) + (slope1 * Power(inraster ,2)) + (0.0056 * inraster)  + 65.864)`

Comment: see also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83885/what-is-the-correct-variable-type-for-a-single-value-in-raster-calculator-model

Answer (score 1):

Just had to add `float()` around `slope1`.